# Which process is updating my /etc/hosts file?

Tags: 20.04

I have edited my /etc/hosts file but when I reboot the undesirable line I edited is added to my /etc/hosts file.

What process is doing this? Where does it get the hostname and the alias from?

Comment: Just to double-check... are you using a LiveCD or a full Ubuntu install?

Comment: I'm using a full ubuntu installation. It is a server. So no GUI.

Comment: Nothing on a default Ubuntu edits /etc/hosts except for 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1+your server name as an alias. There might also be ipv6 versions there. systemd-resolved adds those. systemd-hostnamed does hostname,

Comment: It is a 127.0.0.1 line that is being added. It is adding it with the old server name and the old hostname as an alias. Which process is doing this? Where is it getting the old information from?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04,
And I found the following information in my /etc/hosts

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
```

I've choose option "a" and changed /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl .It resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was a useful suggestion. However, it doesn't seem to be the case for my system. I checked ```/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg``` and ```manage_etc_hosts``` is not set.

Comment: Please try to set the value of manage_etc_hosts explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The actual option to disable in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` to stop `/etc/hosts` being overwritten is - `update_etc_hosts`, and not what is says in the hosts file comments.

To prevent your `/etc/hosts` from being overwritten, comment it out as shown below:

```
# The modules that run in the 'init' stage
cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - seed_random
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - disk_setup
 - mounts
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh
# - update_etc_hosts
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).